# Getting text from a form and evaluate in selenium using ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a registration form and one of the questions before submitting is:

"What is 8 + 4?"

The values will be different every time. I am using Selenium 2 with Ruby and want to to see if anyone knows how to a) get the text from the question and then b) compute the addition and return the correct answer in the field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using ruby code try to get the values in between `is` and `?` Store this in Variable and now split the text with deliminator `+` now you will get the Values in array in different location. Now you can add these two and use for your evaluation. I don't have idea about ruby but its possible in `PHP` as I have done the same. Its should be in Ruby too.

Getting text between is and ? can be done strpos() in php that gives the position of the string see similar function for ruby.